# PyCaffe NetSpec, how to create layers with the same name but different phases?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

Basically I want to generate something like the following `prototxt` in Python.

```
layer {
  name: "image"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "image"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./training_data_paths.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
}
layer {
  name: "image"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "image"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./validation_data_paths.txt"
    batch_size: 64
  }
}
```

These are two versions of the first layer in a network, one for training and one for testing. They have the same name so that the next layer (for example a convolution layer) can take the named layer `image` as input and automatically receive training or testing data depending on the corresponding phases. How do I achieve that using the Python interface? I know that I can do

```
n.image = L.HDF5Data(hdf5_data_param={'source': './training_data_paths.txt',  
                                  'batch_size': 64},
                 include={'phase': caffe.TRAIN})
```

to generate the layer, but I can't do `n.image = (..., include={"phase": caffe.TEST)` after that, because in Python the member `n.image` will be replaced. (Right?)

Comment: see [bvlc/caffe github issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4044)