# defining caffe prototxt in python

Tags: python, caffe, pycaffe

**How to add a layer for both the TRAIN and TEST phase with different parameters in one prototxt file using caffe in python?**

If you look at https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt, you will see the input layer for train and test phase with different parameters.

I followed this links 
[Where is layer module defined in PyCaffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36187825/where-is-layer-module-defined-in-pycaffe)
[LSTM module for Caffe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32225388/lstm-module-for-caffe)
to define caffe prototxt in python.
But i can't define the same layer name with same blob names for different phases in one prototxt file.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open issue https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4044
have a look at these links:
[caffe: model definition: write same layer with different phase using caffe.NetSpec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844968/caffe-model-definition-write-same-layer-with-different-phase-using-caffe-netsp)
[PyCaffe NetSpec, how to create layers with the same name but different phases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541774/pycaffe-netspec-how-to-create-layers-with-the-same-name-but-different-phases)